# Mac M Series Host Only Network with VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtualization, cpu, virtualbox

Has anyone been able to find a workaround to run a Host Only Network on Mac M Chips?

I am trying to run a OVA file on VirtualBox using a Host Only Network so I can set up a server for this class that requires to have a contained dev environment. However, the professor has said that he is of no help to any of the Mac people in class that have M chips.

I have tried using VirtualBox which simply isn't supported anymore, so I tried running an older dev build of VirtualBox and hosting the OVA file but it always just ends in an error. I think since it is trying to access information that it can't reach since the architecture is no longer supported.

I then tried using VMWare and running a Windows 11 machine through that then running VirtualBox through that, which I then found out that VirtualBox doesn't support nested Virtualization.

I haven't seen any solutions regarding this situation so I am just wondering if anybody has found a workaround. I am having to resort to my desktop Windows machine which I can't use in class.

Comment: Is this OVA an Intel VM or an ARM VM?

Comment: @MarcWilson I believe that it is Intel VM and not the ARM.

Comment: I believe that Parallels is Apple Silicon compatible and that VMWare has a public beta of sorts that you could look into that supports Apple Silicon. But it may rely heavily on what OS is in your OVA file and what apps you need to run on top of that. I would bet that you could rent an Apple Intel system on AWS, which would obviate the need for Apple Silicon compatibility.

Comment: if it's an Intel VM, your only choice is to run it under UTM, in emulation.  I'm not familiar with how to feed an OVA to UTM, though.  This may be helpful... https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/discussions/2521